# ubuntu 12.04.5 not able to install mysql server

Tags: mysql

(I am new to Ubuntu)

I need to install mysql server on Ubuntu 12.04.5 and I am getting follwing error.

```
mysql-server Dependes hav unmet dependencies:
mysql-server: Depends : mysql-server-5.5 but it in not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
.....
```

Comment: What command did you run to achieve this error message? Can you please include its *full* output in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, how you got into that situation, but you could update your cache

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try to let `apt-get` resolve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The `-f` flag fixes broken dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the `-f` option is not going to work for you. If it doesn't work, then you have to install the package giving an exact version. In order to do so, you can use `=` to set the version the system wants.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.20-1ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

use this option

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```